# Factorial function not working

Tags: java, android

I'm working on an android calculator app and have all the basic functionality down but when I press the factorial button, it doesn't return anything at all. I don't know why. Please help.

## Eval function

```
public static double eval(final String str) {
    return new Object() {
        int pos = -1, ch;

        void nextChar() {
            ch = (++pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
        }

        void prevChar() {
            ch = (--pos < str.length()) ? str.charAt(pos) : -1;
        }

        boolean eat(int charToEat) {
            while (ch == ' ') nextChar();
            if (ch == charToEat) {
                nextChar();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        double parse() {
            nextChar();
            double x = parseExpression();
            if (pos < str.length()) throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            return x;
        }

        // Grammar:
        // expression = term | expression `+` term | expression `-` term
        // term = factor | term `*` factor | term `/` factor
        // factor = `+` factor | `-` factor | `(` expression `)`
        //        | number | functionName factor | factor `^` factor

        double parseExpression() {
            double x = parseTerm();
            for (;;) {
                if      (eat('+')) x += parseTerm(); // addition
                else if (eat('-')) x -= parseTerm(); // subtraction
                else return x;
            }
        }

        double parseTerm() {
            double x = parseFactor();
            for (;;) {
                if      (eat('x')) x *= parseFactor(); // multiplication
                else if (eat('÷')) x /= parseFactor(); // division
                else return x;
            }
        }

        double parseFactor() {
            if (eat('+')) return parseFactor(); // unary plus
            if (eat('-')) return -parseFactor(); // unary minus

            double x;
            int startPos = this.pos;
            if (eat('(')) { // parentheses
                x = parseExpression();
                eat(')');
            } else if ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') { // numbers
                while ((ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || ch == '.') nextChar();
                x = Double.parseDouble(str.substring(startPos, this.pos));
            } else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z' || ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') { // functions
                while (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'|| ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') nextChar();
                String func = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
                x = parseFactor();
                if (func.equals("sin")) x = Math.sin(x);
                else if (func.equals("cos")) x = Math.cos(x);
                else if (func.equals("tan")) x = Math.tan(x);
                else if (func.equals("log")) x = Math.log(x);
                else if (func.equals("ln")) x = Math.log10(x);
                else if (func.equals("Abs")) x = Math.abs(x);
                //else if (func.equals("fact")) x = CombinatoricsUtils.factorial((int) x);
                else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
            }

            else if (ch == '√') { // functions
                while (ch == '√') nextChar();
                String func = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
                x = parseFactor();
                if (func.equals("√")) x = Math.sqrt(x);
                else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
            }

            else if (ch == '!') { // functions
                int strLength = str.length();
                String func = str.substring(strLength - 1);
                x = parseFactor();
                if (func.equals("!")) x = CombinatoricsUtils.factorial((int) x);
                else throw new RuntimeException("Unknown function: " + func);
            }

            else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected: " + (char)ch);
            }

            if (eat('^')) x = Math.pow(x, parseFactor());
            else if (eat('³')) x = Math.pow(x, 3);
            else if (eat('²')) x = Math.pow(x, 2); // exponentiation

            return x;
        }
    }.parse();
```

Comment: Again you with your calculator :D still not done, ey? :D

Comment: Is this your method that calculates the factorial of an integer? I find that suspicious.

Comment: You commented the factorial's line.......

Comment: @Vucko haha yeah. I've been hitting lots of amateur roadbumps. Feels like the stackoverflow community has written more code for it than I have

Comment: @AkashAggarwal That was an alternative I used, didn't work either. The real one is the one in the else if with ch == '!'

Comment: @Gendarme Why is it suspicious?

Comment: Are the other functions like `ch == square root` working?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Yeah, they're all working perfectly except for the factorial one.

Comment: You can try logging the value of `x` before return statement or in the `if` block  of the function itself

Comment: You have seen the restriction on x for `CombinatoricsUtils.factorial`, i.e. that x must be from 0 to 20? (http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/util/CombinatoricsUtils.html#factorial(int)).

Comment: @ThomasKläger I did see it and it still doesn't work for values between 0 and 20.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I'll log the value of x and post the log statement so you can see.

Comment: Okay, let me know when you've updated the question

Comment: @AkashAggarwal I tried logging the value of x and it didn't work. The log statement doesn't run from within the else if condition. I guess that means the else if block doesn't run at all. Seems to be confusing me more and more.

Comment: A good practice of programming is when you write a program, you log the output everywhere while the program/software is being developed/tested. This is especially useful to find till which statement the program has been covered, known as statement coverage. I'd suggest you to log in each `{}` block suspicious with unique `log tags`. This will help you get rid of confusions.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing your application's code then I can test it myself on my android device. Just put it on any of the git service providers and let me know.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal my internet sucks so it won't really push the project to git. Could you send me your email? I can email the code to you

Comment: virusofminds@gmail.com

Comment: You might want to learn how to debug...

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with a simple test program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(eval("!5"));
}
```

And I got a StackOverflowError, because your code does not skip the `!`

Changing

```
    else if (ch == '!') { // functions
        int strLength = str.length();
        String func = str.substring(strLength - 1);
        x = parseFactor();
```

to

```
    else if (ch == '!') { // functions
         while (ch == '!') nextChar();
         String func = str.substring(startPos, this.pos);
         x = parseFactor();
```

corrected the problem for me.

---

If you do not want to loop over the exclamation mark, you will still need to skip it:

```
    else if (ch == '!') { // functions
         eat('!');  // this is missing in your current implementation
         x = CombinatoricsUtils.factorial((int) parseFactor());
```

---

Currently I have no explanation why the code for "fact" does not work - if I uncomment those lines they seem to work (at least for me).

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it still doesn't work :-(. I wonder if it has something to do with the fact that I casted the variable 'x' from a double to an int. Could this be an issue?

Comment: @DayemSaeed then it has to be something outside of this code. Could you send me your project to so-contact@10a.ch?

Comment: sent the project to your email

Comment: @DayemSaeed you were still missing a `nextChar();` call to advance the `pos` over the exclamation mark.

Comment: Actually I added the exact code you used but it was in my local repository. Didn't commit it since it didn't really work.

Comment: @DayemSaeed one note: as currently written the factorial is a prefix operation (`!5`). It will not work as a postfix operation (`5!`), for that you would have to move the code downwards to where you calculate squares, cubes and exponantiation

Comment: I tried testing it both ways, prefix and postfix. Even the prefix one didn't work

Comment: Well, its fixed by moving the code to where I calculate exponents but it requires the factorial to be multiplied with 1 to give a result. Thanks Thomas.